# Does harrowing strengthen a mage?

Tags: dragon-age-rpg

At the description of the Harrowing in Dragon age's rulebook it says:

> Apostates don’t engage in the Harrowing per se, but most will
>   find a time when they are called upon to enter the Fade and
>   face demonic forces. Those who survive emerge stronger and
>   wiser for the experience;

If a mage triggers a harrowing do they emerge from the experience as stronger with more mana capacity or some other benefit or is that just fluff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's mostly flavor. The actual benefits are already included for characters who did go through the tests (*Circle Mages*). If you look at mages that do not go through the Harrowing (*Apostates*), they are lacking in magical power:

> If you choose to play an apostate, modify your character as
>   follows:
>
> • **Add 1 to your Willpower ability.** An apostate needs
>   strength of will to fend off possession.
>
> • Pick one of the following ability focuses: Cunning
>   (Natural Lore) or Willpower (Self-Discipline).
>
> • Choose whether your character is a human or an elf.
>
> • You can speak and read the Trade Tongue.
>
> • Take the mage class.

But *Circle Mages* don't get that +1 Willpower, they get +1 Magic instead:

> If you choose to play a Circle mage, modify your character
>   as follows:
>
> • **Add 1 to your Magic ability.** This represents the training
>   you have received from your Circle.
>
> • Pick one of the following ability focuses: Cunning
>   (Arcane Lore) or Cunning (Historical Lore).
>
> • Choose whether your character is a human or an elf.
>   Most Circle mages are human, but some elves choose to
>   join to avoid becoming apostates.
>
> • You can speak and read the Trade Tongue and language
>   of your native land, if different from Trade Tongue. You
>   can read Ancient Tevene.
>
> • Take the mage class.

**Magic** not only defines how much mana you got but how much you recover and how strong are the spells you cast. That means that *Circle Mages* are generally more powerful than *Apostates*.

Other than the *Tevinter Laetan* characters (the third option for mages), only circle mages start with that flat +1 Magic bonus. While apostates have a chance (7-8 in 2d6) to gain that +1 Magic bonus, but it's not certain.